# File Manipulation libraries

Tags: java, file, io

I have a project which I need to manipulate files. things like: create new file by a defined structure(header,data,trail). and then I need to things like search/validate/create/read.

basically I want to map the files to objects and vise versa.(I am willing to map them to objects coz it will be much more comfortable for me to manipulate the fields inside each file via object)

I wonder if any of you deal with such things before? and maybe could recommend me on libraries which could easy my work.

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I Found a ORM framework called Canyon which mapping Files to Objects. but still had difficulties. so I have implemented my own ORM file to objects and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at serialization and de-serialization

Comment: serialization  wont help me here. I want my own structure in the file since some1 else need to read it by a specific structure. serialization wont map the object to the file in the way I want it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom mapping, you need custom coding. I would suggest you look at DataInputStream and DataOutputStream.

Using these you can control the header, records and footer in any binary format you want.

I suggest you generate your serialization (if you need to have the afstest possible speed) or use reflections to do the translation. Just using reflection is pretty fast and much simpler than generating code. ;)

Comment: but Serialization will make it binary. I want it to remine text.

Comment: In that case I would serialize as text. ;) With the built in Serialization you have no choice, but if you do it yourself, you can make it anything you want.  For example, all my objects serialize and deserialize in CSV format i.e. you can read it in excel. ;) You could use XML or JSon with XStream.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined file layout with different content you should consider to use a template engine like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) to generate your files.
You can define templates here which will be filled with your dynamic content which you have to provide. Definitly better than to use `System.out` (I mean hard code your template text).

A library which helps for basic file manipulation is [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

If you realy want to map your files to objects than it would be a Serialization/Deserialization as Angelom mentions. Many libraries help you to do this but the file format is fixed:

JSON: [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) 
XML: [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)

Comment: Are those libraries able to sanely produce binary output? As far as I know they are focused on text-based output formats.

Comment: @Joachim The libraries work with text output (that is what _rayman_ needs if I understand it correct).

Comment: He doesn't mention if he wants text or binary, actually but from what I understand he want's the library to help him with parsing/reading as well. And that's where those template libraries fall flat.

Comment: He want's text (see comment in answer from Lawrey). Using templates to generate his files will definitly help - particularly if his files contains lot text around the object info. You are right - reading is not included - thus I only mentioned generation of his files. I tried to give help and some ideas - I thought that would be requested. Unfortunately I do not know the library he want's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file read by 3rd party as well, how about using some popular existing exchange format such as CSV or XML?

XML is fully supported in standard library. There's plenty of CSV libraries out there, including [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/).

Comment: I am not required to use XML format. only a specific format which is defined by the company. that format is TXT and I wanted to convert all those files to objects.. something like ORM